# Automating RFID reader testing

Tags: embedded

We are trying to automate RFID card reader testing, normally we test bunch of cards (40 to 50) by placing it in front of the reader and seeing if the data from reader matches the expected data. I want to automate this whole test (esp the card placement part)

For 5 to 10 cards we can make a small wheel with arms (controlled by a stepper motor) and attach one card in each arm and rotate the arm so that card comes in front of the reader but if we have to do the same for 40 cards it becomes complex.

Are there any devices or solutions to automate this? New ideas are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[ChameleonMini](https://github.com/emsec/ChameleonMini/wiki)

> The credit-card shaped ChameleonMini is a versatile tool for practical
>   NFC and RFID security analysis, compliance and penetration tests, and
>   various end-user applications. The freely programmable platform can
>   create perfect clones of various existing commercial smartcards,
>   including cryptographic functions and the Unique Identifier (UID). It
>   can be employed to assess security aspects in RFID and NFC
>   environments in different attack scenarios, such as replay or relay
>   attacks, state restoration attacks, sniffing of NFC communication, or
>   functional tests of RFID equipment. New firmware for the ChameleonMini
>   can be comfortably uploaded via a USB bootloader. A convenient,
>   human-readable command set allows to configure its behavior and update
>   the settings and content of up to eight internally stored, virtualized
>   contactless cards. During battery-powered stand-alone operation, the
>   integrated buttons and LEDs enable user interaction and feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, card emulators can help solve one set of issues. We want to test different technology cards (LF, HF) and customer cards with specific data and certs etc, here we cannot use emulators. Different customer cards has different RF behaviours as well that's where we want to deploy some automation.